# Posting a user defined variable in JSON array using CURL

Tags: json, linux, curl, terminal

I have been trying to POST a JSON array from my Linux (UBUNTU) terminal using the following command, and I am trying to post user defined N value

```
N=21;curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"device_id":$N,"lattitude":2323,"longitude":443}' http://192.168.xx.xx:XXXXX/api/gps/
```

N=21 is my defined value and I want to pass N value as one of the JSON parameter
**It is throwing a parse error.**
Is there any alternative way, to pass user defined values.
Can you suggest a way where I can achieve this?

Comment: Use " instead of ', and \" instead of "

Comment: Alternatively, you may split the JSON into variables and concatenate them when composing the `curl` parameters: `N=21; START='{"device_id":'; END=',"lattitude":2323,"longitude":443}'; curl ... -d "$START$N$END" ...`

Comment: Dmitry Egorov!!! Thanks a tonn!!! it's working. But can we do it without concatenating, and why isn't working the normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably seems a **temporary solution**, by concatenating the respective strings.

```
N=21; START='{"device_id":';

END=',"lattitude":2323,"longitude":443}';
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$START$N$END" http://ipadress.com/path/to
```